# Where does Maven get the url it uses to download poms

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, ip-address

For **some** projects, `maven` seems to have problems building the right URL.

I am getting the failure:

> Failed to execute goal on project Test: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.oldcurmudgeon:Test:jar:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies for [..., com.google.guava:guava:jar:15.0 (compile), commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1 ...]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.14: Could not transfer artifact org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:pom:1.7.14 from/to uk.maven.org (http://uk.maven.org/maven2): Connect to **uk.maven.org:80** **[uk.maven.org/*23.235.43.209*]** failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]

I don't understand where the *23.235.43.209* is coming from? Is it in configuration or something? Some `pom.xml` or `settings.xml`?

I **can** browse to http://uk.maven.org/maven2 fine.

I **can** browse to uk.maven.org:80 fine.

I **CANNOT** browse to uk.maven.org/23.235.43.209.

The IP address is clearly the problem but what can I do to track down where this ip is coming from?

**Added**

The `settings.xml` in the `.m2` folder (as mentioned by @KoustavRay) reads:

```
  ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>Repositories</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>Maven.org Repository for Maven</name>
          <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>apache</id>
          <name>Maven.org Repository for Apache</name>
          <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>java.net</id>
          <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
          <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
   ...
```

So no mention there of the strange ip address. It turns out that the third one is a bit iffy - it's moved since. However, removing that entry does not solve the problem.

Also the `mirrors` section:

```
<mirror>
  <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
  <name>UK Mirror for maven.org</name>
  <url>http://uk.maven.org/maven2</url>
  <id>uk.maven.org</id>
</mirror>
```

Comment: "By default, Maven will download from the central repository" -- https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html

Comment: can you run `mvn help:effective-settings` and `mvn help:effective-pom` from your project and check the output of these two commands? (Note: output would be verbose, better to redirect to file). There you should spot from where this repository is coming from

Comment: @A.DiMatteo - I normally don't use command-line so I may have gone wrong but all those seemed to do was to try (and fail) to build the project. Using `--help:` doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[uk.maven.org/23.235.43.209]` is not a URL, i assume it's a verbose output to help finding network problems.

`23.235.43.209` *is* the IP of `uk.maven.org`:

```
C:\Users\hinneLinks>nslookup uk.maven.org
Server:  fritz
Address:  10.2.1.13

Nicht autorisierende Antwort:
Name:    sonatype.map.fastly.net
Address:  23.235.43.209
Aliases:  uk.maven.org
          central.maven.org
```

Comment: For those coming later I marked this as the answer because it led me to the answer. The answer I found was to add `-Dhttp.proxyHost=our.proxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=80` to the `Maven` options in Netbeans.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Then consider configuring a proxy in the Maven settings: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:**

**Answer to Question**:The definition of `central` is in the Maven super POM that is part of the Maven installation. You can mirror this repository if you wish to point your Maven installation to a different central repository.

**Solution**:It is possible that you are not being able to connect due to multiple problems.However,There are several official Central repositories geographically distributed. You can make changes to your settings.xml (at ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml) file to use one or more mirrors. Instructions for this can be found in the guide Using [Mirrors for Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html).
 An example:

```
<settings>
  ...
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>UK</id>
      <name>UK Central</name>
      <url>http://uk.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
     <mirror>
        <id>planetmirror.com</id>
        <name>PlanetMirror Australia</name>
        <url>http://downloads.planetmirror.com/pub/maven2</url>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  ...
</settings>
```

Comment: The settings.xml in conf folder of the installation is called the system settings.xml whereas the `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` is called the user settings.xml file. Usually you should not change the system settings.xml only the user settings.xml (The system settings.xml existed also in Maven 2)

Comment: What is the meaning of "Ans:" and "Soln:" in your answer?

Comment: @KoustavRay - Added relevant contents of `settings.xml` in the question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - **Ans** - *answer*, **Soln** - *solution*.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon That was my assumption, but it makes no sense to use that on stackoverflow in an answer. In my opinion, it is only confusing clutter.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion,edited the answer to make it more clear.
Hope the sample xml provided helps.. Also see:https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: Posted my `mirrors` section - no issue there that I can see.

Comment: Try the second mirror that i provided..
`<mirror>
        <id>planetmirror.com</id>
        <name>PlanetMirror Australia</name>
        <url>http://downloads.planetmirror.com/pub/maven2</url>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>`
your mirror is where it is giving error due to some reason.If adding that too doesn't help,then I am sorry

Answer (score 0):

When you build a Maven’s project, the pom.xml file will be parsed, if it see the log4j Maven coordinate, then Maven search the log4j library in this order :

Search log4j in Maven local repository.
Search log4j in Maven central repository.
Search log4j in Maven remote repository (if defined in pom.xml).
This Maven dependency library management is a very nice tool, and save you a lot of work.
There are several official Central repositories geographically distributed. You can make changes to your settings.xml.Currently, the mavenSW central repository is located at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2. You can find this URL specified in the super pom.xml file in maven-2.0.8-uber.jar at org/apache/maven/project/pom-4.0.0.xml.

Sometimes, it can be useful to utilize a public mirror of the central repository. For instance, on the rare occasion that the central repository is down, you could specify to use a mirror of the repository rather than the central repository. Also, if there is a mirror that is geographically close to you, there could be a time savings in utilizing a public mirror. A list of several mirrors exists at http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html.